# ARC and releasing memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have read many articles online, and I am a bit confused about ARC. I will list my questions below, please help me answer them.

1.) What does the keyword `strong` do (in `@property (nonatomic, strong) …`)?

2.) Don't we have to `release` or `autorelease` what we `alloc` anymore, because I get a warning saying that I need not have to. (I am not at my Mac, so I can't copy the warning I got.)

3.) I couldn't find the Leaks tool in Xcode 4.2. Where did it go? Or don't we have to check for leaks anymore?

4.) When creating the project using Xcode 4.2, I clicked on "enable ARC", so will my program work on iOS 3? (I think ARC only supports iOS 4 and above.)

Comment: Please post these as separate questions.

Comment: I think they are all related.

Comment: Tim's answer is very good, but you should still read the documentation, for your own benefit.

Comment: @Nick Toumpelis You again! :)

Comment: @Tim Kemp In the swamp... again :)

Answer (score 7):

1. `strong` is an ARC analog to `retain` (there's no `retain` under ARC). It means that property value will be hold by class where the `@property` was defined, and released upon reassignment or dealloc. (Note that under ARC there's no need to release or nullify properties in dealloc).
2. The point of ARC is taking care of `retain`/`release` routine by compiler, so there's no need for manual memory management methods.
3. You can check for leaks by running Profile (`Product -> Profile` menu) and selecting Leaks instrument. Leaks can be introduced with cyclic references or in CoreFoundation code (ARC doesn't work with CoreFoundation). Also if you are mixing ARC and non-ARC code, the latter could be a source of leaks.
4. ARC is supported by OS starting from iOS 4.0 (though iOS 5 SDK is needed). The key difference between 4.0 and 5.0 ARC support is availability of `weak` property specifier. Weak property (`__weak` variable) will be automatically nullified when the `strong` value it refers to is released. There are no `weak` properties in 4.0, so `__unsafe_unretained` specifier should be used (It's a close analog to `assign` specifier, it doesn't retain value and can point to already deallocated value, so it's dangerous).

Here's a great explanation of ARC:
[Everything you need to know about automatic reference counting](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/)

Comment: ARC is supported for iOS4.3 onwards - not 4.0.

Comment: ARC doesn't work with CoreFoundation, so leaks could be introduced in CF code. Also if you are mixing ARC and non-ARC code, the latter could be a source.

Comment: I'm a bit late here, but ARC is actually supported starting iOS 4.0, not 4.3.

Comment: @danyowdee Seems you are right. I've found a discussion in comments to an answer stating 4.0+ is supported either: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7747801/153651.

Comment: @Abizern Looks like you were wrong with arc on 4.0 (see a discussion by the link in a comment above)

Answer (score 6):

1. Strong is equivalent to `retain` in ARC. It indicates ownership: [What does the "strong" keyword do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613186/what-does-the-strong-keyword-do)
2. No, that's done for you. ARC inserts those statements in (compiled) code automatically. That's its main job. But, per Abizern's comment, this only works for your objects and Cocoa objects. If you're using Core Foundation (`CF*`) classes then you must read about the `__bridge` family of casts. [You might start reading here.](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)
3. It's in Instruments. Per iHunter's answer, Cmd+I or Product->Profile, then choose Leaks. Particularly important given (2).
4. It will not work.

Comment: +1. Regarding #2, you shouldn't be getting a warning; you should be getting an error. It's not that you don't have to use `release`. It's that you *must* not use `release`.

Comment: So do we still have to test for leaks ? If ARC is releasing memory then why should we test for leaks?

Comment: ARC only deals with Cocoa objects. If you are using Core Foundation objects you still have to use memory management. There are rules for transferring ownership of objects when using toll-free bridging. ARC doesn't make memory management go away - it just makes the more common parts of it easier and more efficient. So, yes - you still need to check for leaks.

Comment: Also if you have cycles in your object graph, they will not be deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are already three answers that cover the main things so I'll focus on a single detail here, that isn't already mentioned:

> 3.) I couldn't find the Leaks tool in Xcode 4.2. Where did it go? **Or don't we have to check for leaks anymore?**

Yes we do still need to check for leaks:

ARC is not garbage collection, it is automated retain/release.

Thus, it is still possible — in fact, it's pretty easy — to create leaks!

Consider the following example:

```
@class Puppet;
@protocol PuppetDelegate : <NSObject>
- (void)puppetDidTwistStrings:(Puppet *)puppet;
@end

@interface Puppet : NSObject {
    id <PuppetDelegate> delegate_;
}

- (id)initWithPuppetDelegate:(id <PuppetDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)unravelStrings;

@end

@implementation Puppet
- (id)initWithPuppetDelegate:delegate
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    delegate_ = delegate;

    return self;
}

// assume some implementation for unravel strings

@end

@interface MasterOfPuppets : NSObject <PuppetDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *puppets_;
}

- (void)puppetDidTwistStrings:(Puppet *)puppet;
- (void)bringOutAPuppet;

@end

@implementation
- (id)init
{
     if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

     puppets_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     return self;
}

- (void)bringOutAPuppet
{
    Puppet *newPuppet = [[Puppet alloc] initWithPuppetDelegate:self];
    [puppets_ addObject:newPuppet];
}

- (void)puppetDidTwistStrings:(Puppet *)puppet
{
    BOOL isOurPuppet = [puppets_ containsObject:puppet];
    if (!isOurPuppet) return;

    [puppet unravelStrings];
}
@end
```

This example is (admittedly) a little stupid, but this code will leak, and ARC is not going to help you about it, whereas garbage collection would:

- A MasterOfPuppets can have many puppets, which he stores in an instance variable — so far so good.
- A Puppet has a delegate which it is going to inform if its strings are entangled — and here it starts.

Whereas in non-ARC code an instance variable was simply a pointer that was being assigned to, ARC assumes that if you stash something in a variable, you want to cling on to it and it will `retain` the value unless **you** tell it not to.

So you have a classical retain-cycle here and ARC won't save you from those.

This may seem a contrived and far-fetched example, but it's not: I've seen this quite a bit in delegate relationships.

(The solution, by the way, is pretty simple: declare `Puppet`'s `delegate_` instance variable as `weak` and everything works as it should.)

Comment: To be honest, this problem (cyclic reference leaking) exists even in GC environments. It's hard for GC to decide which link to break first.